# Can't apply to direct child when usein :hover

Tags: css, hover

I have a problem with the following css approach.

```
.element:hover > div > span {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

On the other hand the following is working

```
.element:hover div > span {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

Why is it invalid to use the upper one and is there a workaround for it?

Comment: please provide HTML. It would be best if you gave a working example.

Comment: Who said it's invalid? Its perfectly valid. This only means that your div is not sitting DIRECTLY inside the .element

Comment: Surely if the lower one works, that's your workaround?